# json filter fails with >#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>

Tags: json, logstash

I'm trying to process entries from a logfile that contains both plain messages and json formatted messages. My initial idea was to grep for messages enclosed in curly braces and have them processed by another chained filter. Grep works fine (as does plain message processing), but the subsequent json filter reports an exception. I attached the logstash configuration, input and error message below.

Do you have any ideas what the problem might be? Any alternative suggestions for processing plain and json formatted entries from the same file?

Thanks a lot,
Johannes

Error message:

```
Trouble parsing json {:key=>"@message", :raw=>"{\"time\":\"14.08.2013 10:16:31:799\",\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"thread\":\"main\",\"clazz\":\"org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory\",\"line\":\"214\",\"msg\":\"Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0'\"}", :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
```

logstash conf:

```
file {
        path => [ "plain.log" ] 
        type => "plainlog" 
        format => "plain" 
    }
}
filter {
  # Grep json formatted messages and send them to following json filter
  grep {
    type => "plainlog"
    add_tag => [ "grepped_json" ]
    match => [ "@message", "^{.*}" ]
  }
  json {
    tags => [ "grepped_json" ]
    source => "@message"
  }
}
output { 
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

Input from logfile (just one line):

```
{"time":"14.08.2013 10:16:31:799","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","clazz":"org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory","line":"214","msg":"Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0'"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding a ***target*** to the json filter.
The documentation does say the ***target*** is optional but apparently it isn't.

Changing your example you should have:

```
json {
  tags => [ "grepped_json" ]
  source => "@message"
  target => "data"
}
```

Comment: By the way, after replying to this I noticed that the documentation I was referring to is for version 1.2.0. I tested the new version and it no longer requires the **target**